# how to downgrade Node.js driver version

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, server

because I have windows 32-bit I am forced to use MongoDB version that using only 4 wires that's why when I wanted to connect MongoDB server with node , I got this Error
[image]

after long search I find that I have to either use a driver which supports protocol version 4 or a server which supports protocol version 6 (the last option option is not possible due to the 32-bit problem).
but there's no article on the internet explain how to downgrade the driver to one which supports protocol version 4 , there's only articles about how to downgrade NodeJS version and NPM , I will be thankful if someone can suggest a solution

Comment: Windows 32-bit - we are in year 2022!

Comment: for some reasons i cannot  buy new laptop so i have to learn with this

Comment: Windows 64-bit should not require a new laptop. In worst case a new Windows license for 10-20 US$ What about MongoDB cloud service (MongoDB Atlas)?

Comment: i search about that but i found that my cpu is x86 and doesn't support 64 bit windows, and I'm new to mongodb and Node.js generally i have no idea about the mongodb cloud and i used to learn offline after downloading all programs and files that i need

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `mongodb` package version prior to 4.2:

> v4.2.0
> Release Highlights
> NODE-3469,NODE-3615,NODE-3507: update min and max wire versions (#3014) (2a78d5a): Updates the minimum wire version for the driver to 6 (MongoDB 3.6) and max wire version to 14 (MongoDB 5.1)

Comment: thank you for answering, sorry this looks like another question but I've tried hard , I've installed mongodb package 2.2.12 by running this command in terminal npm install mongodb@2.2.12 but it still showing  the same error , what i have to do after installing this mongodb package to be able to connect to mongodb , thanks again sir

Comment: What exact error messge does  he 2.2.12 version show you?

Comment: it showing the same error message in the image of the question

Comment: What exact version of MongoDB do you use?

Comment: i am using mongoDB version 3.2.16 because i have only 32-bit os

Comment: Looking at https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/compatibility/ I see you selected the correct version of 2.2.12. Are you sure you restrted your service after updating `mongodb`?

Comment: sorry but I'm not sure what do you mean by restarting my service

Comment: Restart Node.js app

Comment: yes of course, i also installed old version of node.js which is 7.10.1